# Taking Video/Photo With ImagePickerController And Using Them On Different View

Tags: swift, ios8, uiimagepickercontroller, segue

Can someone guide me in the right direction on how to use a photo or video just taken from imagepicker in another view.

Say I call it from my main view when pressing a camera button. I want to take a picture or video and then use it. I would like to do this in another view where I can have different custom buttons that would allow me to share it to Facebook, what-have-you as well as get back to my main view. How would I go about doing this?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Cop Watch
//
//  Created by James Combs on 4/16/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 James's Source Code. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, CameraViewControllerDelegate,  UITextViewDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet internal var photosButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet internal var cameraButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet internal var goodBadInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet internal var stoppedInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet internal var ethnicityInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet internal var nameInput: UITextField!

internal var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController?
internal var camViewController: CameraViewController?
internal let camSourceError = "Camera is not available"

private var hasCancelledVideo: Bool = false
private var hasCancelledPhoto: Bool = false
private let cameraViewIdent = "CameraViewController"
private let photoViewIdent = "PhotoViewController"


    // Tried doing things here but unsure how to use this correctly for now with image picker
func cameraViewControllerDidFinish(controller: CameraViewController, imagePicker: UIImagePickerController) {

    /*imagePicker.delegate = self

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    }

    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    controller.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)*/
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == self.cameraViewIdent {

            // Get a reference to the camera view controller - I THINK I COULD COMBINE THESE 2 IN ONE
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? CameraViewController {

        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == self.photoViewIdent {

            // Get a reference to the photo view controller
        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? PhotosViewController {


        }
    }
}

@IBAction func didPressPhotosButton(sender: AnyObject) {

}

@IBAction func didPressCameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    self.imagePickerController!.delegate = self

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        self.imagePickerController!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
    }

    var availableMediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(self.imagePickerController!.sourceType)

    self.imagePickerController!.mediaTypes = availableMediaTypes!
    self.imagePickerController!.allowsEditing = false
    self.presentViewController(self.imagePickerController!, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
    UITextField Delegates
*/

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

    goodBadInput.resignFirstResponder()
    stoppedInput.resignFirstResponder()
    ethnicityInput.resignFirstResponder()
    nameInput.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in  `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:`

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    var photo = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
```

Use the key `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` to get the video URL in case of capturing video

Comment: I recently have chosen to use that. How would I use that function to display the image or video on a different view though. I would like to be able to use other custom buttons besides the one on my main view. Also, I can get an image to display but cannot get videos to display